# Columnas con tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

estoy intentando poner columnas en mi programa y lo hice de esta manera:

```
    # Tabla
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=[f"#{n}" for n in range(0, 4)])
    self.tree.config(show='headings')
    self.tree.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan = 2) 
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='id', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#1', text='Nombre', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#2', text='Combo', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#3', text='Precio', anchor=CENTER)
```

pero no me funciona y creo que mi error esta en esta parte de mi codigo:

```
# Get Products from Database
def get_products(self):
    # cleaning Table 
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    # getting data
    query = 'SELECT * FROM 7030 ORDER BY name DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    # filling data
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row["nombre"], values = row["combo"])
```

Soy nuevo y no se que varibles usar dentro de " Self.tree.insert() "

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Bro, si no me equivoco, para mostrar todos los valores de tu consulta, que si no me equivoco, son 4(id, nombre, combo, precio). yo lo hice de esta forma `self.tabla.insert('', 0, text = row[0], values = row[1:])`, para que en la tabla de texto, motrase el primer valor(el id), y en el resto, mostrase los valores que sobren.

Respecto al error, no entiendo cual es el problema directamente, ¿puedes hacer un edit explicando mejor tu problematica?

Comment: Te puedo pasar el resto de mi código? No me compila, discúlpame si te molesto!

Comment: No es molestia bro. No recuerdo mucho de Tkinter, pero viendo puedo recordar algun patron y ver si puedo ayudarte en algo. Disculpa que responda tarde

Answer (score -1):

Si te sirve de algo, este es un código de un proyecto que hice hace mucho tiempo, el cual funcionaba, e incluso, tenía una scrollbar vertical.

```
    self.framebot=Frame(self.master)
    self.framebot.grid(row=1,columnspan=6)
    ttk.Button(self.framebot, text="MODIFICAR", command=self.ModificarCliente).grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=W+E, padx=(120,0))
    ttk.Button(self.framebot, text="ELIMINAR", command=self.EliminarCliente).grid(column=1,row=0, sticky=W+E)
    ttk.Button(self.framebot, text="ACTUALIZAR", command=self.ActualizarCliente).grid(column=2,row=0, sticky=W+E)
    self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(self.framebot, height = 7, selectmode='browse')
    self.tabla.grid(row=1,columnspan=4)
    """esto crea y asigna el scrollvar"""
    self.scrollbar_vertical = ttk.Scrollbar(self.framebot, orient='vertical', command = self.tabla.yview)
    self.scrollbar_vertical.grid(row=1,column=5, sticky=N+S)
    """Esto hace que la barra desplazadora funcione"""
    self.tabla.configure( yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_vertical.set)
    self.tabla["columns"]=("#0","#1","#2","#3", "4")
    self.tabla.column("#0", width=100, minwidth=100)
    self.tabla.column("#1", width=150, minwidth=150)
    self.tabla.column("#2", width=100, minwidth=100)
    self.tabla.column("#3", width=100, minwidth=100)
    self.tabla.column("#4", width=250, minwidth=250)
    self.tabla.column("#5", width=80, minwidth=80)

    self.tabla.heading("#0",text="Cédula:")
    self.tabla.heading("#1",text="Nombre")
    self.tabla.heading("#2",text="Tipo")
    self.tabla.heading("#3",text="Teléfono")
    self.tabla.heading("#4",text="Domicilio")
    self.tabla.heading("#5",text="Disponible")
```

Recuerda que cuando creas una sección, debes asignarla a un cuadro padre, para que esta sepa a qué cuadro pertenece(no recuerdo como se le dice)